# Make notification link clickable and open in browser or youtube depending on link

Tags: javascript, android

[image: my app image]

I have created an app for sending  notification but when I send a link in notification it is not clickable.

What I want is to make it clickable when I send a link like youtube or any website link and it opened in the YouTube or browser.

Comment: how are you storing the elements in the list? if you have a model... you can put an onitemclicklistener, get the position of your click, then get the URL (if it is)

Comment: I have a model ..

Comment: then does what i say make no sense?